# ImportError: cannot import name 'Base' from 'schema'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, importerror

I am receiving the following error and I cannot find any circular dependencies.

> **ImportError: cannot import name 'Base' from 'schema'**

I've organized my code into packages, like so:

```bash
customers/__init__.py
customers/customers_db.py
customers/schema.py
setup.py
```

**schema.py** (depends on SqlAlchemy)

```py
from typing import List
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()
```

**customers_db.py** (depends on schema.py)

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os
from schema import Base, Contact, Address
```

**setup.py** (depends on customers_db.py)

```py
import customers.customers_db as db
```

There are no errors when running customers_db.py in the interpreter, by itself. The error occurs when running setup.py.

**Update**

Here is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\devroot\PyCustomer\src\setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    import customers.customers_db as db
  File "C:\devroot\PyCustomer\src\customers\customers_db.py", line 4, in <module>
    from schema import Base, Contact, Address
ImportError: cannot import name 'Base' from 'schema' (C:\devroot\PyCustomer\.venv\Lib\site-packages\schema.py)
```

Comment: In the customers_db.py, if I change the import to "from .schema import Base, Contact, Address", then the setup.py script works.  However, the customers_db.py script cannot be run on its own without error (ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package)

Comment: Try from `customers.schema import ...`

Comment: If you want to keep the relative import, you need to run your customers_db.py with the `-m` flag:
`python -m customers.customers_db`

Comment: @snakecharmerb, setup.py works with the import like that, but running cusomers_db.py results in 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\devroot\PyCustomer\src\customers\customers_db.py", line 4, in <module>
    from customers.schema import Base, Contact, Address
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customers'`

Comment: @elbashmubarmeg, I see.  I am able to run using the -m flag when I am in my home directory.  That helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the customer_db.py file needs to reference schema.py using a relative path, so the top-level module may find it.

```py
from .schema import Base, Contact, Address
```

Running the customer_db.py on it's own is then done from the top-level directory, using the -m option.

```bash
$ python -m customers.customers_db
```

Comment: hah, reduced ads from my die 